# Set Permalink On Wapka Site

Tags: url, permalinks

friends I am a Wapka - Site Builder User & My question is how can I customize my Wapka Permalink
intially it looks like
yoursite.wapka.me/site_1.xhtml.
after adding my domain name
mydomain.com/site_1.xhtml
However that isn't my problem
I want to change rest of url i.e /site_1.xhtml
It is possible to change it as site_xyz.xhtml but how to change it to xyz.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

yes you can ! Just go to Edit site > Change title >  there are two rows, write xyz in both. 
`name:
xyz
URL:xyz`
 Then click button below it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in Wapka to do like that , Wapka autoindexing function never allow the members to do permalink